# How to use a state as the height for a div in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been working on a project which requires the user to input the height and width through which a div would be displayed of the provided dimensions.

The state is being updated but the height of the div is not changing.

```js
import { useState } from "react"
import './App.css'

function App() {
  
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const handleInput = e => {
    setHeight(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sheet Cutter</h1>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Height" onChange={handleInput} value={height}/>
      <div className="sheet" style={{height: {val}}}>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I tried another method in which I used increments to update the height and that was working but that way is not practical

Comment: Where does `{val}` come from? If it's defined somewhere else, it would be `{{ height: val + 'px' }}` instead of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 errors in the code fragment that you shared.

- `val` is not defined anywhere. You should be using the state `height` instead of an undefined variable.
- You are not adding `px` at the end.

  ```
     <div className="sheet" style={{height: `${height}px`}}>
     </div>
  ```

Comment: It worked, actually the val state was height before I just forgot to change it back to height.